# Redirecting from cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to redirect to a different view depending on the result of a dataset, but I keep getting returned to the page I am currently on, and can't work out why. I drop into the if statement the action gets called but once i return the view to the new page, it returns me back to the current page.

CSHTML page

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Search Results";
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> custs = ViewBag.Customers;

bool anyRows = custs.Any();
if(anyRows == false)
{


    Html.Action("NoResults","Home");


}
// redirect to no search results view
```

}

Controller

```
 public ActionResult NoResults()
    {
       return View("NoResults");

    }
```

View I cant get too..

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "NoResults";
 }

<h2>NoResults</h2>
```

Comment: Why can't you redirect to another action from controller?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Change to this:

```
@{ Response.Redirect("~/HOME/NoResults");}
```

Comment: Why would i want to return back to action.. I want to return the view

Comment: that command does not seem to be available anymore.

Answer (score 12):

Would be safer to do this.

`@{ Response.Redirect("~/Account/LogIn?returnUrl=Products");}`

So the controller for that action runs as well, to populate any model the view needs.

> **Source**
>   [Redirect from a view to another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080515/redirect-from-a-view-to-another-view)

Although as @Satpal mentioned, I do recommend you do the redirecting on your controller.

Answer (score 1):

This clearly is a bad case of controller logic in a view. It would be better to do this in a controller and return the desired view.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Results() 
{
    EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> custs = ViewBag.Customers;
    bool anyRows = custs.Any();

    if(anyRows == false)
    {
        return View("NoResults");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("OtherView");
    }
}
```

Modify NoResults.cshtml to a Partial.

And call this as a Partial view in the parent view

```
@Html.Partial("Results")
```

You might have to pass the Customer collection as a model to the Result action or in a ViewDataDictionary due to reasons explained here: [Can't access ViewBag in a partial view in ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729784/cant-access-viewbag-in-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc3)

The `ChildActionOnly` attribute will make sure you cannot go to this page by navigating and that this view must be rendered as a partial, thus by a parent view. cfr: [Using ChildActionOnly in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253769/using-childactiononly-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to method of same controller..using this line , and if you want to pass some parameters to that action it can be done by writing inside ( new { } )..
Note:- you can add as many parameter as required.

@Html.ActionLink("MethodName", new { parameter = Model.parameter })