# Calling a new View as page loads

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know this isn't the right way, but my server host doesn't give me much choice. But I need to call `HomeControllers` `Index` method and return the `View` it has. 
But I need it to be done in the `C#` section of my `default.cshtml` when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a new view is nothing but redirecting your application to a new url. If you want to redirect to a new url from view,

```
@{
   Response.Redirect("~/Controller/action");
}
```

safest way could be,

```
  @{ Response.Redirect("~/Account/LogIn?returnUrl=desiredUrl"); }
```

Article on redirect from view to view is [Here !!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080515/redirect-from-a-view-to-another-view)