# Redirecting to another view is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i want to redirect from view1 to view2, but it is not working and i cannot figure out why. it stays on the same view (path is still: "Home/view1" and i want it to be "Home/view2)". please help.

in my 1. view:

```
Html.Action("View2", "Home", new { id = siteid });
```

in my home-controller:

```
public ActionResult View2(int id) 
{

   var model = new View2ID();
   model.site1ID = id;
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: `@Html.Action()` renders the view returned by the `View2` method in the existing view. It does not do a redirect. For that you need to generate a link - `@Html.ActionLink("View2", "View2", "Home", new { id = siteid }, null )`

Comment: @StephenMuecke you know how i can automatically call the link? because the "html.action(..)" is in a if-condition and if the if-condition is true i want to redirect it to view2. now with the html-actionlink, view1 gets build with that link and when i click on it, it redirects me to the desired view. but i want that i dont even have to click on that link. hope its clear what i mean with that

Comment: That makes no sense. If you have logic that should redirect to a different page, then that code goes in the controller, and you redirect in the controller method to the appropriate view.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do redirect from the view you want to use

```
@{ Response.Redirect(Url.Action("View2", "Home", new { id = siteid }); }
```

Anyway, I believe it is better to do the redirect from controller action before view is going to be rendered. So, far the condition is probably known at that time.

```
public ActionResult View1(int id) 
{
   ...logic you already have there

   if(condition) {
       RedirectToAction("View2", "Home", new { id = siteId });
   }

   return View(model);
}
```

Related links:

[Redirect from a view to another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080515/redirect-from-a-view-to-another-view)