# Redirect to chosen page after login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In order to authorize only logged in users to specific pages I have used:

```
[Authorize(Roles="administrator")]
[Authorize(Roles="subscriber")]
```

Administrator and subscriber are the only roles on my website. Now this works when a user that is not logged in tries to access pages to witch he is not authorized he automatically gets redirected to the login page. The problem appears after the user logs in; I want to redirect him to the page he tried to access before.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Forms Authentication module passes a `ReturnUrl` in the query string when it redirects the user to the LogOn page. Look at your browser address bar when this LogOn form is shown.

So once you successfully logged on you could redirect to this url.

The default AccountController that was created for you when you created the MVC application even has an example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Notice how the LogOn action takes a ReturnUrl parameter and if authentication succeeds, we redirect the user to the page he was initially requesting.

But obviously this can only work if the target url is accessible with a GET request.

Comment: how can I make this work if I get redirected to the login page after an ajax call , because as it stand after I login I get redirect to something like this : http://localhost:9133/Account/LogIn?ReturnUrl=%2fProducts%2fAddToCart%3fProductId%3d8%26X-Requested-With%3dXMLHttpRequest&ProductId=8&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest

Comment: For AJAX calls, I've already [`answered your question`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14080571/29407). What you have to do in the `ajaxComplete` handler is to add the currently requested url as ReturnUrl query string parameter before redirecting using `window.location.href`. Then the LogOn action will redirect to the target url upon successful login.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Request.QueryString["returnurl"] != null) return Redirect(Request.QueryString["returnurl"]);
```